# Go test terminal output

Tags: go

The Go test tutorials I have searched use the return value to the testing.

I would like to write a test that checks the output from the terminal.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

*main.go*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    arguments := os.Args   

    fmt.Println(strings.ToUpper(arguments[1]))
}
```

The test I have played around with

*main_test.go*

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "testing"
)

type checkResult struct {
    inp      string
    expected string
}

var testCases = []checkResult{
    {"Go <3", "GO <3"},
}

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range testCases {
        output, err := exec.Command("go run main.go ", test.inp).Output()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        if string(output) != (test.expected) {
            t.Fatal("Expected result is wrong")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The command is `go` with arguments `"run"`, `"main.go"` and `test.inp`.  Use this code: `output, err := exec.Command("go",  "run",  "main.go ", test.inp).Output()`.

Comment: Note that this isn't really checking the output "from the terminal".  The standard output of that command isn't a terminal it's handled entirely within Go.  The fact that the output *could* be a terminal isn't really very relevant - you're checking the output of the command, not something to do with terminal.  There's nothing inherently terminal related about `os.Stdout` `os.Stdin` or `os.Stderr`, they're just file streams like everything else .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change design of your CLI little bit, it will be more testable. Create global variable of type `io.Writter` and use `fmt.Fprintf` to write your output into `os.Stdout`.

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

var out io.Writer = os.Stdout

func main() {
    arguments := os.Args

    fmt.Fprintf(out, "%s\n", strings.ToUpper(arguments[1]))
}
```

Now it is no problem to set variable `out` to redirect output and `os.Args` to CLI arguments in test scenario.

**main_test.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "os"
    "testing"
)

func TestOutput(t *testing.T) {
    testData := []struct {
        Args   []string
        Output string
    }{
        {
            Args:   []string{"./macli", "hello"},
            Output: "HELLO\n",
        },
        {
            Args:   []string{"", "Go <3"},
            Output: "GO <3\n",
        },
    }
    for _, test := range testData {
        // Init test
        os.Args = test.Args
        out = bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
        // Run test
        main()
        // Evaluate output
        if actual := out.(*bytes.Buffer).String(); actual != test.Output {
            t.Errorf("expected '%s', but got '%s'", test.Output, actual)
        }
    }
}
```

For more detailed description see this [article](https://medium.com/swlh/unit-testing-cli-programs-in-go-6275c85af2e7)